# Draw an arc in opengl GL10

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, automatic-ref-counting

I want to draw an arc using center point,starting point,ending point on opengl surfaceview.I have tried this given below code so far. This function draws the expected arc if we give the value for **start_line_angle** and **end_line_angle** manually (like **start_line_angle**=0 and **end_line_angle**=90) in degree.

But I need to draw an arc with the given co-ordinates(center point,starting point,ending point) and calculating the **start_line_angle** and **end_line_angle** programatically.
This given function draws an arc with the given parameters but not giving the desire result. I've wasted my 2 days for this. Thanks in advance.

```
 private void drawArc(GL10 gl, float radius, float cx, float cy, float start_point_x, float start_point_y, float end_point_x, float end_point_y) {
        gl.glLineWidth(1);
        int start_line_angle;
        double sLine = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((cy - start_point_y) / (cx - start_point_x)));   //normal trigonometry slope = tan^-1(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) for line first
        double eLine = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((cy - end_point_y) / (cx - end_point_x)));         //normal trigonometry slope = tan^-1(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) for line second

        //cast from double to int after round
        int start_line_Slope = (int) (sLine + 0.5);


        /**
         * mapping the tiriogonometric angle system to glsurfaceview angle system
         * since angle system in trigonometric system starts in anti clockwise
         * but in opengl glsurfaceview angle system starts in clock wise and the starting angle is 90 degree of general trigonometric angle system
         **/
        if (start_line_Slope <= 90) {
            start_line_angle = 90 - start_line_Slope;
        } else {
            start_line_angle = 360 - start_line_Slope + 90;
        }

//        int start_line_angle = 270;
//        int end_line_angle = 36;

        //casting from double to int
        int end_line_angle = (int) (eLine + 0.5);

        if (start_line_angle > end_line_angle) {
            start_line_angle = start_line_angle - 360;

        }
        int nCount = 0;

        float[] stVertexArray = new float[2 * (end_line_angle - start_line_angle)];

        float[] newStVertextArray;
        FloatBuffer sampleBuffer;

//        stVertexArray[0] = cx;
//        stVertexArray[1] = cy;

        for (int nR = start_line_angle; nR < end_line_angle; nR++) {
            float fX = (float) (cx + radius * Math.sin((float) nR * (1 * (Math.PI / 180))));
            float fY = (float) (cy + radius * Math.cos((float) nR * (1 * (Math.PI / 180))));

            stVertexArray[nCount * 2] = fX;
            stVertexArray[nCount * 2 + 1] = fY;
            nCount++;
        }

        //taking making the stVertextArray's data in reverse order
        reverseArray = new float[stVertexArray.length];//-2 so that no repeatation occurs of first value and end value
        int count = 0;


        for (int i = (stVertexArray.length) / 2; i > 0; i--) {
            reverseArray[count] = stVertexArray[(i - 1) * 2 + 0];
            count++;
            reverseArray[count] = stVertexArray[(i - 1) * 2 + 1];
            count++;
        }

        //reseting the counter to initial value
        count = 0;
        int finalArraySize = stVertexArray.length + reverseArray.length;
        newStVertextArray = new float[finalArraySize];

        /**Now adding all the values to the single newStVertextArray to draw an arc**/

        //adding stVertextArray to newStVertextArray
        for (float d : stVertexArray) {
            newStVertextArray[count++] = d;
        }

        //adding reverseArray to newStVertextArray
        for (float d : reverseArray) {
            newStVertextArray[count++] = d;
        }

        Log.d("stArray", stVertexArray.length + "");
        Log.d("reverseArray", reverseArray.length + "");
        Log.d("newStArray", newStVertextArray.length + "");

        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(newStVertextArray.length * 4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        sampleBuffer = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        sampleBuffer.put(newStVertextArray);
        sampleBuffer.position(0);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, sampleBuffer);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, nCount * 2);
        gl.glLineWidth(1);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of arc are you trying to draw using 3 points? Is this a circular arc or an oval arc? Or a bezier curve? What, exactly? I see you pass in a radius; that seems to defeat the purpose of using 3 points.

Comment: honestly I dont want to use the radius because if we have start point and center point we can calculate the radius too. We can ignore radius but in this function calculating the points on the circle we need radius too so I used this. I need circular arc. I dont know how to achieve the result. and I am new in opengl-es too :(

Comment: The OpenGL ES part is essentially irrelevant; as long as you can draw line segments, the question is just which line segments to draw to form your arc. The problem is that a center and 2 points do not form a *circular* arc. You would have to restrict the two points to both being on the circle.

Comment: Sir, Do you have any sample source code to achieve this goal :)

Answer (score 0):

To begin with the trigonometry you may not simply use the `atan` to find degrees of the angle. You need to check what quadrant the vector is in and increase or decrease the result you get from `atan`. Better yet use `atan2` which should include both `dx` and `dy` and do the job for you.

You seem to create the buffer so that a point is created per degree. This is not the best solution as for large radius that might be too small and for small radius this is way too much. Tessellation should include the radius as well such that number of points `N` is `N = abs((int)(deltaAngle*radius*tessellationFactor))` then use `angleFragment = deltaAngle/N` but make sure that `N` is greater then 0 (`N = N?N:1`). The buffer size is then `2*(N+1)` of floats and the iteration if `for(int i=0; i<=N; i++) angle = startAngle + angleFragment*i;`.

As already pointed out you need to define the radius of the arc. It is quite normal to use an outside source the way you do and simply force it to that value but use the 3 points for center and the two borders. Some other options that usually make sense are:

- getting the radius from the start line
- getting the radius from the shorter of the two lines
- getting the average of the two
- interpolate the two to get an elliptic curve (explained below)

To interpolate the radius you need to get the two radiuses `startRadius` and `endRadius`. Then you need to find the overall radius which was already used as `deltaAngle` above (watch out when computing this one, it is more complicated as it seems, for instance drawing from 320 degrees to 10 degrees results in `deltaAngle = 50`). Anyway the radius for a specific point is then simply `radius = startRadius + (endRadius-startRadius)*abs((angleFragment*i)/deltaAngle)`. This represents a simple linear interpolation in polar coordinate system which is usually used to interpolate vector in matrices and is the core functionality to get nice animations.

There are some other ways of getting the arc points which may be better performance wise but I would not suggest them unless and until you need to optimize your code which should be very late in production. You may simply keep stepping toward the next point and correcting the radius (this is only a concept):

```
        vec2 start, end, center; // input values
        float radius; // input value

        // making the start and end relative to center
        start -= center;
        end -= center;

        vec2 current = start/length(start) * radius;  // current position starts in first vector

        vec2 target = end/length(end) * radius; // should be the last point

        outputBuffer[0] = current+center; // insert the first point
        for(int i=1;; i++) { // "break" will need to exit the loop, we need index only for the buffer
            vec2 step = vec2(current.y, -(current.x)); // a tangential vector from current start point according to center
            step = step/length(step) / tessellationScale; // normalize and apply tessellation

            vec2 next = current + step; // move tangentially
            next = next/length(next) * radius; // normalize and set the

            if(dot(current-target, next-target) > .0) { // when we passed the target vector
                current = next; // set the current point
                outputBuffer[i] = current+center; // insert into buffer
            }
            else {
                current = target; // simply use the target now
                outputBuffer[i] = current+center; // insert into buffer
                break; // exit
            }
        }
```

Comment: I solved the problem by simply modifying these lines as :

double sLine = Math.abs(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((cy - start_point_y) / (cx - start_point_x))));    
        double eLine = Math.abs(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((cy - end_point_y) / (cx - end_point_x))));      

        int tStart = (int) (sLine + 0.5);
        int tEnd = (int) (eLine + 0.5);

Comment: and finally this :

  int start_line_angle = 90 - tStart;
        int end_line_angle = 90 - tEnd;
        int temp = start_line_angle;

        /**
         * because staring angle is always smaller than then ending angle
         */
        if (start_line_angle > end_line_angle) {
            start_line_angle = end_line_angle;
            end_line_angle = temp;
        }

Comment: Well I hope you did the tests for all the quadrants.. For instance start = (-.1, -1.0) end = (-.1, 1.0) center = (0,0)